# Подключение к локальной базе MySQL из контейнера Docker

Tags: python, mysql, docker, sqlalchemy, pymysql

Система на win 10. На ней установлен MySQL сервер.
Через докер создан контейнер.
На нем будет запускаться всякий Python код, получать данные и отправлять их из среды контейнера на локальный MySQL сервер.
Как такое подключение организовать?

Сейчас при выполнении кода в контейнере получаю ошибку:([Errno 111] Connection refused)
Подключение происходит через библиотеки sqlalchemy и pymysql - Python код - create_engine('mysql+pymysql://{user_name}:{pass}@{ip}:{port}/{database_name}')

Уже пытался создать новое соединение через MySQL Workbench указывая адрес контейнера - не помогло.
В конфиг ~\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini добавлял bind-address=0.0.0.0 - не помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы подлючиться из контейнера к базе, которая запущена на хосте, можно воспользоваться `host.docker.internal` ([Docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds)), т.е. в вашем случает эту строку нужно вставить вместо `ip`.